# Bernoulli's inequality variation

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality, induction

To prove: $(1+a_1)(1+a_2)\ldots(1+a_n)\geq\dfrac{2^n}{n+1}(1+a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n)$ when $a_i\geq1$

This seems to be based on Bernoulli's Inequality (which can be proved by induction).

Trying the induction way, the given problem holds for $n=1$.

For $n=2$, I get $3a_1a_2\geq1+a_1+a_2$ which is true when $a_i\geq1$.

For $n=3$, I get $a_1a_2+a_2a_3+a_1a_3+a_1a_2a_3\geq1+a_1+a_2+a_3$ which is true.

But how do I take it up to general case ?

For every step, the RHS increases exponentially.

LHS grows like $1+\sum{a_i}+\sum\limits_{i\neq j}{a_ia_j}+\sum\limits_{i\neq j\neq k}{a_ia_ja_k}+\cdots$ which is polynomial.

So, does that make the problem wrong or is there some other way to look at this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

let $a_{i}-1=b_{i},i=1,2,\cdots,n$,
$$\Longleftrightarrow (b_{1}+2)(b_{2}+2)\cdots(b_{n}+2)\ge\dfrac{2^n}{n+1}(b_{1}+b_{2}+\cdots+b_{n}+n+1)$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow 2^n\left(1+\dfrac{b_{1}}{2}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{b_{2}}{2}\right)\cdots\left(1+\dfrac{b_{n}}{2}\right)\ge\dfrac{2^n}{n+1}(b_{1}+b_{2}+\cdots+b_{n}+n+1)$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow \left(1+\dfrac{b_{1}}{2}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{b_{2}}{2}\right)\cdots\left(1+\dfrac{b_{n}}{2}\right)\ge\dfrac{1}{n+1}(b_{1}+b_{2}+\cdots+b_{n})+1$$
use Bernoulli's inequality,we have
$$(1+a_{1})(1+a_{2})\cdots(1+a_{n})\ge 1+a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n}$$
so
$$\left(1+\dfrac{b_{1}}{2}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{b_{2}}{2}\right)\cdots\left(1+\dfrac{b_{n}}{2}\right)\ge 1+\dfrac{1}{2}(b_{1}+b_{2}+\cdots+b_{n})$$
and it is clear
$$\dfrac{1}{2}(b_{1}+b_{2}+\cdots+b_{n})\ge\dfrac{1}{n+1}(b_{1}+b_{2}+\cdots+b_{n}),n\ge 1$$
By done!

Comment: So beautiful .. Thanks a lot !! :)